# Multiple Loss Functions For Proper Parameter Updates

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss

I am working on a model on PyTorch where it has two loss functions each fed from two separate input datasets. I want to update the model parameters based on these loss functions, **ic_loss**, **res_loss**, and also record their respective values each epoch. I highlighted by *### 1 ###*, *### 2 ###* and *### 3 ###* the lines of code that I modified. It seems to me that both **Code 1)** and **Code 2)** do the same thing, but I doubt otherwise. Here are three alternatives from the training part of my code that I am not sure of which to pick:

**Code 1)**

```
    self._model.train()

    for epoch in range(1, self._epoch_number + 1):

      loss_info_string = f'Epoch number: [{epoch} / {self._epoch_number}] - '
      ic_loss_val = 0.0
      res_loss_val = 0.0

      for ic_input in self._ic_loader:

        u_hat = self._model(torch.cat(ic_input, dim=1))
        ic_loss = self._ic_loss(u_hat, ic_input)
        ic_loss.backward() ### 1 ###
        ic_loss_val += ic_loss.item()

      ic_loss_val /= len(self._ic_loader)

      loss_info_string += f'Initial Condition error/loss: {ic_loss_val:.6e}'

      for res_input in self._res_loader:

        u_hat = self._model(torch.cat(res_input, dim=1))
        res_loss = self._res_loss(u_hat, res_input)
        res_loss.backward() ### 1 ###
        res_loss_val += res_loss.item()

      res_loss_val /= len(self._res_loader)

      loss_info_string += f' - Residual error/loss: {res_loss:.6e}'

      self._optimizer.step() ### 2 ###
      self._optimizer.zero_grad() ### 3 ###

      loss_info_string += f' - Total error/loss: {ic_loss_val + res_loss_val:.6e}'
```

**Code 2)**

```
    self._model.train()

    for epoch in range(1, self._epoch_number + 1):

      loss_info_string = f'Epoch number: [{epoch} / {self._epoch_number}] - '
      ic_loss_val = 0.0
      res_loss_val = 0.0

      for ic_input in self._ic_loader:

        u_hat = self._model(torch.cat(ic_input, dim=1))
        ic_loss = self._ic_loss(u_hat, ic_input)
        ic_loss.backward() ### 1 ###
        self._optimizer.step() ### 2 ###
        self._optimizer.zero_grad() ### 3 ###
        ic_loss_val += ic_loss.item()

      ic_loss_val /= len(self._ic_loader)

      loss_info_string += f'Initial Condition error/loss: {ic_loss_val:.6e}'

      for res_input in self._res_loader:

        u_hat = self._model(torch.cat(res_input, dim=1))
        res_loss = self._res_loss(u_hat, res_input)
        res_loss.backward() ### 1 ###
        self._optimizer.step() ### 2 ###
        self._optimizer.zero_grad() ### 3 ###
        res_loss_val += res_loss.item()

      res_loss_val /= len(self._res_loader)

      loss_info_string += f' - Residual error/loss: {res_loss:.6e}'

      loss_info_string += f' - Total error/loss: {ic_loss_val + res_loss_val:.6e}'
```

**Code 3)**

```
    self._model.train()

    for epoch in range(1, self._epoch_number + 1):

      loss_info_string = f'Epoch number: [{epoch} / {self._epoch_number}] - '
      ic_loss_val = 0.0
      res_loss_val = 0.0

      for ic_input in self._ic_loader:

        u_hat = self._model(torch.cat(ic_input, dim=1))
        ic_loss = self._ic_loss(u_hat, ic_input)
        ic_loss_val += ic_loss.item()

      ic_loss_val /= len(self._ic_loader)

      loss_info_string += f'Initial Condition error/loss: {ic_loss_val:.6e}'

      for res_input in self._res_loader:

        u_hat = self._model(torch.cat(res_input, dim=1))
        res_loss = self._res_loss(u_hat, res_input)
        res_loss_val += res_loss.item()

      res_loss_val /= len(self._res_loader)

      loss_info_string += f' - Residual error/loss: {res_loss:.6e}'
      
      (ic_loss + res_loss).backward() ### I ###
      self._optimizer.step() ### II ###
      self._optimizer.zero_grad() ### III ###

      loss_info_string += f' - Total error/loss: {ic_loss_val + res_loss_val:.6e}'
```

**Code 1)** and **Code 3)** seem to be the same except for if I used a batch size different from the entire datasets since **Code 1)** would accumulate gradients for each batch whereas **Code 3)** would use only the last batch. Therefore, I discarded **Code 3)**. Is that correct?

Also based on what I tried to described above, which one should I consider using, **Code 1)** or **Code 2)**? I hope everything is clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you want to update the model with a single `.backward()` call to a combined loss, similar to what you're doing in version 3. However, version 3 only calls the gradient update after going through both dataloaders - you want to do it every batch. Something like this

```
ic_iter = iter(self._ic_loader)
res_iter = iter(self._res_loader)
for i in range(iterations):
    ic_input = next(ic_iter)
    u_hat = self._model(torch.cat(ic_input, dim=1))
    ic_loss = self._ic_loss(u_hat, ic_input)

    res_input = next(res_iter)
    u_hat = self._model(torch.cat(res_input, dim=1))
    res_loss = self._res_loss(u_hat, res_input)

    loss = ic_loss + alpha*res_loss # alpha scaling parameter
    loss.backward()
    self._optimizer.step()
    self._optimizer.zero_grad()
```

If the dataloaders are different lengths, you'll have to figure out the right cadence for refreshing the iterators.

Comment: Thanks to your reply that made me remember that I code on Python, I found an even simpler solution to this by making use of `sum()` function with embedding the "for-loop" as generators for both cases and summing them up for `backward()` as such: `ic_loss = sum(self._ic_loss(self._model(torch.cat(ic_input, dim=1)), ic_input) for ic_input in self._ic_loader)` with `(ic_loss + res_loss).backward()`.